# Visual Studio Online scheduled build can't find my branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, deployment, automation, continuous-integration

I have created a Build Definition in Visual Studio Online which points to an "External Git" repository hosted at BitBucket. The details are set up under the "Repository" tab as follows:
[image: Repo Setup]

When I manually queue a build, using the "Queue build..." button, everything works as expected. My log is as follows:

```
2015-07-22T07:07:50.0285647Z Syncing repository: NxGN.OpenCast (Git)
2015-07-22T07:07:53.6355527Z Checking out origin/dev to C:\a\6268f160\NxGN.OpenCast
2015-07-22T07:07:53.9928992Z Checked out branch dev for repository NxGN.OpenCast at commit 9a658c94a1045df5656a654c780f5b7d1c2809f4
```

My problem is that for a scheduled build, configured like [image: Scheduled Build]
it fails with the following log:

```
2015-07-22T07:20:24.0976453Z Syncing repository: NxGN.OpenCast (Git)
2015-07-22T07:20:26.6424255Z Checking out +origin/dev to C:\a\6268f160\NxGN.OpenCast
2015-07-22T07:20:26.6724252Z ##[error]No valid git object identified by '+origin/dev' exists in the repository.
```

I have tried specifying the branch as `dev`, `origin/dev`, `refs/heads/dev`, all of which place a `+` at the beginning of the branch name in the produced log.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe that `+` is part of a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

In that case, try as value (beside the "Include" field):

```
dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev
```

Comment: @Corpsekicker can you try with `dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev`?

Comment: Could you edit the original answer with the dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev solution?